# Containment of $\sigma$-algebras generated by random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ denote a probability space and consider a random vector $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ is
$$\sigma (X) = \{ X^{-1} (B) : B \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R}^m) \}$$
Now consider a constant matrix with full column rank $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $n < m$. Then $(A^T X) : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a random variable. We can write the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A^T X$ as
$$\sigma (A^T X) = \{ (A^T X)^{-1} (B) : B \in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R}^n) \}$$
I want to show that 
$$\sigma (A^T X) \subseteq \sigma (X)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally let $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ be a Borel-measurable function.

For every set $B\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ we have: $$(f\circ X)^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$$

If $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$ then $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^m)$ and consequently the RHS is an element of $\sigma(X)$.

Proved is now that $\sigma(f \circ X)\subseteq\sigma(X)$.

Every $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ that can be represented by a matrix is Borel-measurable.